# Result from database - Array cannot be coerced into Float (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, typeerror

I retrieved a Float value from my database and tried to add it to a Float type value and I get an error: `in '+': Array cant be coerced into Float (TypeError)`

```
total = 0.0
db = SQLite3::Database.open "Checkout.sqlite"

for i in 0..@items.length
    tempPrice = db.execute "SELECT price FROM Products WHERE product_code = ?", @items[i]
    total = total + tempPrice
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0.0
db = SQLite3::Database.open "Checkout.sqlite"

for i in 0..@items.length
    db.execute("SELECT price FROM Products WHERE product_code = ?", @items[i]) do |row|
        total = total + row[0]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`tempPrice` is array, you should use `tempPrice[0]` if you sure it's have only 1 value, or you can use `tempPrice.sum` if result can have multiple values.

UPD:
try

```
total = 0.0
db = SQLite3::Database.open "Checkout.sqlite"

@items.each do |item|
    db.execute("SELECT price FROM Products WHERE product_code = ?", item) do |row|
        total = total + row[0]
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried tempPrice[0] a while ago and got the same error and I tried tempPrice.sum and got: undefined method 'sum' for [[45.00]]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: try to debug, put `p tempPrice` before `total = total + tempPrice`

Comment: It doesnt say anything else really except what it said before: in 'block in total' in 'each' in 'total'